# When to use 'Upon' instead of 'on'?

Tags: grammar

When to use 'Upon' instead of 'on'? Is there any thumb rule for it?

Comment: The preposition upon is generally much more formal than on but can be used to replace it in certain situations.http://www.onestopenglish.com/community/your-english/word-grammar/your-english-word-grammar-upon/550905.article

Answer (score 0):

The preposition upon is by nature thought to be a more formal way of saying on. And though there don't seem to be any strict rules regarding it's usage yet in some contexts depending on the level of formality involved using "upon" may seem a rather unfitting by coming off a little unnatural though still correct in meaning.